# Sitecore Azure PaaS ARM templates doesnt support template idempotence

Tags: azure, paas, arm-template

We are using `ARM templates` to install `Sitecore 9.2.0 XP Scaled topology` for our infrastructure. While using these templates, we observed that these templates are not idempotent in nature. We needed to deploy this template twice to recreate the environment. In the second run, when we run the template in incremental mode, we encountered a file lock issue on the log file of one of the web app resources.
Since we are doing the changes in ARM templates, we are not able to test the changes without deleting the existing resource because ARM deployment fails due to the idempotency bug in the template.

---

Does anyone know how to make this work?

Comment: short answer ARM templates suck, try using Azure CLI.

Comment: The templates are idempotent, but the SQL database is not.